# Java - Send socket using ObjectStream

Tags: java, sockets, server, tcp, client

I have a Socket that I would like to send from Client to Server (or reverse).

Why can't it be done using ObjectStream when `java.net.Socket` falls under `java.lang.Object` ?  How could I do it correctly?

This is ***Server.java*** :

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);       // make server on localhost:1234
        Socket socket = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Connection from " + socket + "!\n");

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

        Socket receivedSocket = (Socket) objectInputStream.readObject();
        System.out.println(receivedSocket);

        ss.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

This is ***Client.java***:

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234); // make socket on localhost:1234

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(socket);     // send `socket` over network

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

On the `Client` side, it throws me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1192)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:352)
    at com.company.Client.main(Client.java:14)
```

And this on the `Server` side:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1696)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:495)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:453)
    at com.company.Server.main(Server.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1192)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:352)
    at com.company.Client.main(Client.java:14)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you can't. It doesn't make sense. Can you fax a fax machine?

Comment: Can you share more information about what you're trying to accomplish with this capability? That's probably the only way anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write objects that implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface. You could create a configuration class that contains information from the Socket:

```java
public class SocketConfiguration implements Serializable {
    
    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public SocketConfiguration(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
}
```

Though the above example would be pointless since all of this information is already known to you. You could also make a class that extends `java.net.Socket` and implements `java.io.Serializable` but I really don't see the point in doing so.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't help me. Anyway, I appreciate your help, thank you for that.

Comment: @pingupingu what is it you're trying to achieve? If you must write a socket through an object output stream then u can make a class that extends socket and implements serializable.

Comment: @StanvanderBend No you can't. All that will get serialized will be the attributes of the subclass. Not the attributes of the non-serializable `Socket` class, such as the socket descriptor, or any of its other state. In any case the concept doesn't begin to make sense.